# Find rows with a given difference between values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

For a data.table (or data.frame) in R, I wish to find all rows which contain a value in column 'value' which are a given distance 'distance' from another that value in row with the same key. So, given the following:

```
distance <- 22
   key value
   A     1
   B     1
   C     1
   D     1
   A     4
   B     4
   A    23
   B    23
   B    26
   B    26
   C    30
```

I would like to annotated the original table with a count of how many rows exist with the same key, and a value that is +22 from it:

```
  key value count
  A     1     1
  B     1     1
  C     1     0
  D     1     0
  A     4     0
  B     4     2
  A    23     0
  B    23     0
  B    26     0
  B    26     0
  C    30     0
```

I don't really know where to begin with this self-referential approach to manipulating data in R. My initial attempts involved creating a second table and trying to match against that, but that seemed a strange and poor approach.

Note: I'm using the `data.table` package but I'm happy to work from data.frame in this case if that makes things easier.

Reproducible:

```
require(data.table)
source <- data.table(data.frame(key=c("A","B","C","D","A","B","A","B","B","B", "C"),value=c(1,1,1,1,4,4,23,23,26,26,30)))
result <- data.table(data.frame(key=c("A","B","C","D","A","B","A","B","B","B","C"),value=c(1,1,1,1,4,4,23,23,26,26,30),count=c(1,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` based solution. I'll be interested to learn what (if any) improvements can be made to it.

```
# Your code
library(data.table)
source <- 
data.table(data.frame(key = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","A","B","B","B", "C"),
                      value = c(1,1,1,1,4,4,23,23,26,26,30)))
```

That strange `data.table(data.frame(...` is because `data.table()` has an argument called `key`, too. That's one way to create a `data.table` with a column called `"key"`.  Capitalising to avoid the argument name conflict illustrates the more standard syntax :

```
source <- data.table(Key = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","A","B","B","B","C"),
                     Value = c(1,1,1,1,4,4,23,23,26,26,30))
```

Next to avoid needing `as.integer()` later, we'll change the type of the `Value` column from `numeric` to `integer` now. Remember than `1` is `numeric` in R, it is `1L` that is `integer`. It is usually better for efficiency to store `integer` data as `integer`, than `integer` as `numeric`. The next line is easier than typing lots of `L`s above.

```
source[,Value:=as.integer(Value)]   # change type from `numeric` to `integer`
```

Now proceed

```
distance <- 22L
setkey(source, Key, Value)

# Heart of the solution (following a few explanatory comments):
#  "J()"   : shorthand for 'data.table()'
#  ".N"    : returns the number of rows that matched a line (see ?data.table)
#  "[[3]]" : as with simple data.frames, extracts the vector in column 3

source[,count:=source[J(Key,Value+distance),.N][[3]]]
source
      key value count
 [1,]   A     1     1
 [2,]   A     4     0
 [3,]   A    23     0
 [4,]   B     1     1
 [5,]   B     4     2
 [6,]   B    23     0
 [7,]   B    26     0
 [8,]   B    26     0
 [9,]   C     1     0
[10,]   C    30     0
[11,]   D     1     0
```

Note that `:=` changed `source` by reference directly, so that's it. But `setkey()` also changed the order of the original data. If retaining the original order is required, then:

```
source <- data.table(Key = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","A","B","B","B","C"),
                     Value = c(1,1,1,1,4,4,23,23,26,26,30))
source[,Value:=as.integer(Value)]   
source[,count:=setkey(copy(source))[source[,list(Key,Value+distance)],.N][[3]]]

      Key Value count
 [1,]   A     1     1
 [2,]   B     1     1
 [3,]   C     1     0
 [4,]   D     1     0
 [5,]   A     4     0
 [6,]   B     4     2
 [7,]   A    23     0
 [8,]   B    23     0
 [9,]   B    26     0
[10,]   B    26     0
[11,]   C    30     0
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the line that assigns result$count? What is the .N for, and the [[3]]?

Comment: Sure. I just added a few comments in the code, which begin to unpack the data.table call's compact syntax.

Comment: @Ina  Oops, did you really want to retain the original table's order? I missed that bit.

Comment: Nope, no need to retain order. In reality it's a keyed data table anyway so my tables as written out are misleading, and would be sorted by key when printed in R.

Comment: @Ina Ok. Added back an order preserving version, just in case :)

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Excellent edits all. I wasn't satisfied with the `DT$count <-` construct, and now see how it can always be avoided. (It does take a while to start visually parsing the nested `[]`s that are such a big part of effective `data.table` usage. In my case, it's taken about 5 months to really start to get it, but I think I'm just about there.) Thanks as usual for your help.

Comment: @Josh That's quick. It's taken me 5 years!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mapply` to loop through all combinations of key and value:

```
data.table(t(mapply(function(key,val) 
      c(key=key,value=val,count=length(source$value[source$key==key & source$value>(val+distance)]) )
   , as.character(source$key),source$value)))
```

Comment: This seems to produce the wrong results, I get a count of 2 in the second row and a count of 1 in the third row with this formula. I think I understand what it's doing but I can't see an obvious typo that would make this a simple error. Also, ideally the answer wouldn't be n^2 in complexity, but that may not be possible.